# pyautogui.displayMousePosition() does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui, python-3.9

*I am just a beginner with python*, I am following a tutorial to make a simple bot which clicks everytime it sees black.

I have installed pyautogui; 'pip install pyautogui' and imported it.
When I enter this command to display my mouse position: `pyautogui.displayMousePosition()`, it displays this error:

````
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    pyautogui.displayMousePosition()
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 1735, in displayMousePosition
    pixelColor = pyscreeze.screenshot().getpixel(
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 134, in wrapper
    raise PyScreezeException('The Pillow package is required to use this function.')
pyscreeze.PyScreezeException: The Pillow package is required to use this function.```
I have no clue what's going on, can anyone help? I am using **python 3.9.0** and I am on **Windows 10.**
The tutorial I'm using is https://youtu.be/YRAIUA-Oc1Y
If you want more information on what I've installed and done before this, thanks.
````

Answer (score 3):

You can use a lower version of python (3.7) or istall pillow with (pip install pillow)

Comment: I figured it out but thanks anyway, I needed to install python 3.7 and i also didn't have pillow installed.